# Is there a plugin to validate jQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a jQuery plugin which can check our code before launch it ?

Example:

I write this :

```
jQuery('.myclass')css('color','red');
```

The plugin will show me some message like 'parse error line ...' because I forgot a period

Or:

```
function test() {
    alert('test');
...
tet();
```

Message: The `tet()` function doesn't exist.

EDIT: or maybe it could be some Firefox plugin ?

Comment: jQuery is **not** a programming language.  JavaScript is the language you're coding in.

Answer (score 5):

This can't be a plugin because if you have syntax errors in your code, the browser will stop execution and show an error. [JSLint is an online service](http://www.jslint.com/) you could use to validate your javascript.

Comment: And if we wrap our code in a validation function ?
And if the code is valid: document.write(our code)
else alert('some errors ...');

What do you think ?

BTW : I already know JSLint but it's not efficient when you are coding... But useful when you have finished coding...

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the above suggestions, you may also want to look at [**jQuery-lint**](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-lint/) - a script that checks your jQuery codes as they run and report incorrect or suboptimal usage usage of the jQuery API.

Answer (score 0):

As 'Darin Dimitrov' said jQuery is not a language to have some special syntax but it is a javascript library so the syntax validation should be done against javascript

If you are using a IDE like [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) there are javascript plugins like [spket](http://www.spket.com/), [aptana](http://www.aptana.org/) which will help you to find out some syntax errors